# iOS7 call, mail, etc icons in the phone app to put in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uiimage

In the phone app, when you select a contact, it will show you the phone details.  Beside the phone number, there is message icon and phone icon.  Is this available in the code?  How to put it in UITableViewCell.

Comment: You may be able to steal those icons with [the iOS Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple does not make those available through any standard API.

You can create your own easily enough. Screen scrape them or use https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor and see of the images are in there.